# unsigned long long to std::chrono::time_point and back

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I am very confused about something. Given:

```
std::time_t tt = std::time(0);
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp{seconds{tt} + millseconds{298}};
std::cout << tp.time_since_epoch().count();
```

prints something like: `16466745672980000` (for example)

How do I rehydrate that number back into a `time_point` object? I find myself doing kooky things (that I'd rather not show here) and I'd like to ask what the correct way to do the rehydration is.

Comment: `time_since_epoch` is going to give you the amount of time it has been since the epoch of the clock, not the time point.  Most epochs use the unix epoch of 1/1/1970.

Comment: What result are you looking to get?  That `tp` is 298 milliseconds more than `tt`?

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes. `tp` is 298 milliseconds more than `tt`. Howard has been incredibly helpful in his answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
system_clock::time_point tp{system_clock::duration{16466745672980000}};
```

The units of `system_clock::duration` vary from platform to platform.  On your platform I'm guessing it is <sup>1</sup>/<sub>10</sub> of a microsecond.

For serialization purposes you could document that this is a count of <sup>1</sup>/<sub>10</sub> microseconds.  This could be portably read back in with:

```
long long i;
in >> i;
using D = std::chrono::duration<long long, std::ratio<1, 10'000'000>>;
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, D> tp{D{i}};
```

If the native `system_clock::time_point` has precision as fine as `D` or finer, you can implicitly convert to it:

```
system_clock::time_point tp2 = tp;
```

Otherwise you can opt to truncate to it with a choice of rounding up, down, to nearest, or towards zero.  For example:

```
system_clock::time_point tp2 = round<system_clock::duration>(tp);
```

Comment: Which means it would not be save for serialization and possible transfer?

Comment: It would be safe for serialization if you know you're reading it back using the same std::lib/platform, or if the serialization documents the units, or if the format is yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.fffffff, or some other self-documenting format.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Thanks Howard! I was tying myself up in knots trying to figure out what the resolution of the number is. So, you're saying if this number will be rehydrated in a different platform/stdlib, it's not safe for serializing? Is there an alternative?

Comment: I'll add to the answer...